# How to add box-shadow in in react-native?

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native, stylesheet

I am trying add boxshdow to my components, which should have styling as `box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(58,55,55,0.1);` from styleguide.
[image]
When I add it in my code as

```
shadow: {
    shadowColor: 'rgba(58,55,55,0.1)',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
    shadowOpacity: 0,
    shadowRadius: 15
 }
```

Seems nowhere close the the design. Tried adding `elevation`, but not sure hot to convert `box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(58,55,55,0.1);` to an `elevation` number.
Any suggestions please?

[image]

Comment: For android, you just have to put `elevation: 3` in your sttyle object. You can change the 3 btw.

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting back. :)
umm, how are you calculating the elevation? Is there a method to calculate it?

Comment: Also, after adding `elevation: 3` did give me a box effect at bottom part not all around it. Is there a way to add all around the card?

Comment: You don't have to calculate it, set it to whatever makes sense in your design. The bigger is the number the higher will be the shadow.

Comment: That would be a perspective now. ya thanks, works for now.
But would be great if there's more of a logical numbering.

Comment: @SubhenduKundu https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping check this out